# what does the revolute joint's effort limit be zero mean?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 <joint name="joint_1" type="revolute">
  <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="link_1"/>
  <limit effort="0" lower="-2.87979" upper="2.87979" velocity="4.36332"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
</joint>
```

hello, from above can see the effort limit is set to zero, I want to know what does this mean?
*another question:*
now I am using an abb industrial arm in ROS, when start it's gazebo launch  the arm will not fall down. I have some puzzle about this, because the arm link has it's own mass. Thank you for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245847/what-does-the-revolute-joint%27s-effort-limit-be-zero-mean?/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A limit of 0 basically means *no limit*.

For ROS-Industrial robot support packages, a 0-limit is used to either indicate that there is no limit, or that the manufacturer hasn't disclosed it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-10-17**:
Oh, thank you, could you also give me some tips about the second question? I have one of my own robot arm urdf that was exported from solidworks, but when simulated in gazebo, the arm link would fall down because of it's gravity. Is it something wrong like the mass value in my urdf model?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-18**:
In general it's not a good idea to ask two questions in a single ROS Answers question, even if they are related.

I'm not a Gazebo expert, might be that you have gravity disabled on the links in question, or that the mass is not correct, or something else.

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-10-18**:

Gazebo/Orange
true

ok, thank you very much! you are right, the link gravity is turned off in xacro file, I just find it.

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-10-18**:
Hi, gvdhoorn, I find that when the effort limit was set to zero, the joint would not move, I have test it by change it's urdf.
But in ***abb_irb120_moveit_config*** pkg the ***moveit_planning_execution_gazebo.launch*** can move it, I don't know why.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-18**:
(again: please don't treat ROS Answers like a regular forum. We have a rather strict one question per Q/A convention here).

You've probably configured your gazebo xacro/pkg to use an effort controller. The ABB pkgs are using position controllers for exactly this reason.